# Understanding reference passed as value

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am confused over this piece of code. Even though I have read @John Skeet's blog http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html too, I am still slightly confused over last piece. A diagrammatic representation will be greatly helpful.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> myList = new List<int>();
        myList.Add(100);
        myList.Add(50);
        myList.Add(10);
        ChangeList(myList);

        foreach (var item in myList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ChangeList(List<int> myList)
    {
        myList.Sort();

        List<int> myList2 = new List<int>();
        myList2.Add(3);
        myList2.Add(4);

        myList = myList2;
    }
```

Why output is 10,50, and 100. What is happening in last line myList = myList2; and why no matter I comment the line, or uncomment output still stays the same.

Comment: Why do you expect the output to be different?  The `List<>` created inside the method is never referenced again.  The only thing the method does that affects the list passed to it is sort that list.

Comment: That is the point: nothing happens, because the list was passed by value. If it had been passed by reference, the output would have changed to 3 and 4

Comment: Consider an object as a house, and a reference as the address of the house, and a variable as a post-it note that contains an address of a house. In this case, your `myList` and `myList2` **variables** contains references, when you execute that last statement you erase the previous address, and write in the address of the other house. However, that old house is still standing. Any other post-it notes (variables) where the old address is still written will still refer to the old house.

Comment: Passing a reference by value means you get a new variable with a copy of the reference, ie. you pick a new post-it note and write the same address on it. What you do with your post-it note doesn't change my post-it note.

Comment: Passing a reference **by reference** means I will hold up my post-it note and tell you to use my post-it note, without completely giving it to you. If you erase it, you erase my post-it note, if you write in a new address, you are in effect giving me a new address as well, because you're changing **my** post-it note, **my** variable.

Comment: Upvoted, solely because this is an excellent example of dealing with reference vs. value.

Comment: Thank you @LasseVågsætherKarlsen for excellent analogy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last line has actually no effect, because `myList` is just a variable that holds a *reference to your actual list*. That variable itself is - as *every* argument in C# - *passed by value* to the method making any change to it *within* the method having no effect *on the caller*. This is exactly the same as providing an int to a method:

```
void DoSomething(int a)
{
    a = 3
}
```

Calling this method like `DoSomething(myInt)` won´t change the value of `myInt`, as the number was passed by value. In your example a reference is nothing but a number (or more precisely a memory-adress). Changing that adress in your method has no effect to the outside.

By writing `myList = myList2` you assign a new reference **which has nothing to do with the initial one**.

To achieve this you´ll need the [ref-keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref):

```
private static void ChangeList(ref List<int> myList)
{
    myList.Sort();

    List<int> myList2 = new List<int>();
    myList2.Add(3);
    myList2.Add(4);

    myList = myList2;
}
```

Now call it like this:

```
ChangeList(ref myList);
```

Answer (score 0):

So `List<T>` is a reference type. That means that `myList` holds a reference that points to the storage location of this `List<int>` object. Now you invoke `ChangeList(List<int> myList)` and you might think that `myList` gets changed then.

But you actually passed a local copy of `myList`as a method parameter to `ChangeList`. So you changed the items of the local copy of `myList`, which only exists in the `ChangeList()` method.

By adding `ref` to the method parameter you don't pass a copy of `myList`, you pass the reference to the object, so both `List<int>` objects point now to the same object on the storage. So the values of the items of `myList` in `Main()` gets changed because they both reference the same `List<int>`.

```
private static void ChangeList(ref List<int> myList)
{
    myList.Sort();

    List<int> myList2 = new List<int>();
    myList2.Add(3);
    myList2.Add(4);

    myList = myList2;
}
```

Now you have to invoke the method as well with the `ref` keyword.

```
ChangeList(ref myList);
```